# Python + spark to parse and save logs

Tags: python, performance, logging, apache-spark

I need to parse logs and have got following code. I can see two problems: `map().filter()` may induce some performance penalties and copy-paste block

**parser.py:**

```
class Info(object):
    a = ""
    j = ""
    z = ""
    infoline = ""

    def __init__(self, a, j, z, infoline):
        self.a = a
        self.j = j
        self.z = z
        self.infoline = infoline

# function check if the line parameter is produced by provider 'prov'
# yes - returns certain substring of line
# no - returns None
def get_infoline(line, prov):
   ...

def process(line, prov):
    retA = None
    retJ = None
    retZ = None

    infoline = get_infoline(line, prov)line param from 
    if infoline:
        # filling some of retA, retJ, retZ
        ...
        return Info(retA, retJ, retZ, infoline)
```

**job.py:**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import parser

...

prov = ...
log = sc.textFile(pathTofile)
parsed = log.map(lambda ln: parser.proccess(ln, prov)).filter(lambda i: i)

summaryA = parsed.map(lambda info: (info.a, 1)).reduceByKey(add) \
    .map(lambda (a,b): (b,a)).sortByKey(False) \
    .map(lambda (count, name): ("%s\t%i" % (name, count))) \
    .saveAsTextFile('/output/path/a.tsv')

summaryJ = parsed.map(lambda info: (info.j, 1)).reduceByKey(add) \
    .map(lambda (a,b): (b,a)).sortByKey(False) \
    .map(lambda (count, name): ("%s\t%i" % (name, count))) \
    .saveAsTextFile('/output/path/j.tsv')

summaryZ = parsed.map(lambda info: (info.z, 1)).reduceByKey(add) \
    .map(lambda (a,b): (b,a)).sortByKey(False) \
    .map(lambda (count, name): ("%s\t%i" % (name, count))) \
    .saveAsTextFile('/output/path/z.tsv')
```

Comment: What does the `map` method do? What type of object does it return? `reduceByKey`? `filter`?

Comment: These functions return [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html)

Answer (score 2):

With your first file, `parser.py`:

1. Because the `Info` class' `__init__` method requires the three arguments: `a`, `j`, and `z`, which it then attributes to itself, you can remove the class attributes of the same name, as they become superfluous.
2. Within the `process` method, you set several variables before doing anything; `retA`, `retJ`, and `retZ`, which you set to `None`. If you aren't modifying these objects in place, you can omit these completely and add an `else` statement.

   ```
   if infoline:
       # filling some of retA, retJ, retZ
       return Info(retA, retJ, retZ)
   else:
       return Info(None, None, None)
   ```
3. In the aforementioned `if` statement, you can simply use

   ```
   if get_infoline(line, prov):
   ```

   Rather than setting the `infoline` variable. Then, if you need the result, you can define it within the statement.

Comment: (+1) . ① Thank you. ② Actually, I need `None` for next `filter` call ③ Thank you - I missed `infoline` as `Info` member. I fixed